# Jquery interfering with scrolling active nav pill

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following Jquery:

```
//Change active class when scrolling
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position <= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position >= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > resume.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > contact.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I have three nav pills in the header: Home, Resume, and Contact. When I scroll to a certain section of the webpage, the corresponding pill will become "Active", and thus becomes white font. However, with this code, the default blue background for the nav pills come up. Nothing I do in CSS changes it.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li class="home-class"><a href="#home-page" id="home">Home</a></li>     
            <li class="resume-class"><a href="#resume-page" id="resume">Resume</a></li>         
            <li class="contact-class"><a href="#contact-page" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#home:hover, #resume:hover, #contact:hover,
#home:focus, #resume:focus, #contact:focus,
#home:active, #resume:active, #contact:active {
    background-color: #536872;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
    background-color: #536872;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

How come the background color won't change? It remains the default blue no matter what. Does it have to do with the Jquery? (Once I take out the Jquery, it works as intended. Strange.)

Comment: share your html code too.

Comment: Where are you setting the default blue color? Please add more code.

Comment: I'm not setting it to any color, @Alvaro. It's the default blue color that comes with Bootstrap. I'm trying to override it.